# Photo app does not display photos

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

Recently (~2 weeks), the Windows Photo app does often (~40%) not display the picture that I double clicked. The app is just empty:

[image: Foto app not showing image]

The cursor is a blue "waiting" circle.

In that state, the call stack is

```
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 00000019`06b3eb88 00007ffe`13198037     ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
01 00000019`06b3eb90 00007ffe`10627f01     KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x107
02 00000019`06b3ee90 00007ffe`10626d4c     twinapi_appcore!Event::WaitWithFreeUnusedLibraries+0xc9
03 00000019`06b3f110 00007ffe`10629202     twinapi_appcore!<lambda_aba22e915cba93f52f317319f66b8a2d>::operator()+0x1cc
04 00000019`06b3f230 00007ffe`04d68140     twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationFactory::Run+0x252
```

What can I do to make the app work as reliable as before?

Comment: Open Start, Settings, Apps and scroll down to Microsoft Photos.  Click on Advanced Options, and then Repair and Reset (both).  Close out, restart and test Photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to repair the app in the windows settings:

1. Press Windows + I to open the settings app
2. Go to "Apps"
3. Go to "Apps & Features"
4. Search for the Windows Photos App
5. Click on it to navigate to the options
6. Click the "Repair" button

[image: Step 1-5]

[image: Step 6]

After I repaired it, the Windows Photos app works again.